# XPages Dialog boxes stacking

Tags: dialog, xpages

I got the problem, that my dialog boxes are stacking each time I click the button that opens the dialog. So if I've clicked three times I get this:

[image]

I couldn't find out how to prevent this. No matter which button I click (OK does a partial refresh | Abbrechen (Cancel) does a full update) I get another box each time I click the button.

Code of the button that opens the dialog:

```
<xp:button value="Plan meeting" id="buttonPlanMeeting">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
      var c = getComponent("dPlanMeeting")
      c.show();
    } catch(e) {
      dBar.error(location + e);
    }}]]></xp:this.action>
  </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Code for the complete dialog box:

```
<xe:dialog id="dPlanMeeting" title="Plan meeting" keepComponents="true">
  <xp:panel>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="MBPlanMeeting">
      <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:specialstrings.getString("ccEsgDocWflContentEditInfos.dPlanMeeting.MBPlanMeeting")}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
  </xp:panel>
  <xe:dialogButtonBar>
    <xp:button value="Ok" id="buttonDelegateOk" styleClass="lotusFormButton">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
          //will create a meeting for every day the visit is registered
          var wfDoc:NotesDocument = docApplication.getDocument(true);
          specialMeetingCreate(wfDoc);

          var c = getComponent("dPlanMeeting");
          c.hide();

          var c = getComponent("dMeetingCreated")
          c.show();
        } catch (e) {
          dBar.error(location + e);
        }
       }]]></xp:this.action>
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Cancel" id="buttonDelegateCancel" styleClass="lotusFormButton">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
          var c = getComponent("dPlanMeeting");
          c.hide();
        } catch (e) {
          dBar.error(location + e);
        }
      }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
  </xe:dialogButtonBar>
</xe:dialog>
```

Does this have anything to do with keepComponents? I've tried true and false, but the effect stays the same.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please post your XSP code into your question?

Comment: What version of Domino and what version of Extension Library are you using? I tried the above code on 9.0.1 + ExtLib r12, but couldn't reproduce the issue

Comment: We're using Domino 9.0.1 (no fixpack) and ExtLib 9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that the solution was just to set "keepComponents = false". I've tried that before, but now it'S working. I get the dialog box only once no matter how often I click the button

Comment: Had just been looking at this again this morning, and reproduced the problem with keepComponents=true. The code didn't work with keepComponents=false, so I changed to use these lines instead: `var c = getComponent("dPlanMeeting");
var d = getComponent("dMeetingCreated");
c.hide();
d.show();`